# Number of requests per minute in java

Tags: java, automation, throughput

I have a output which is has follows:

```
Timestamp:1509383899190 Value:20171030224102
hbase Timestamp 2017/10/30 22:48:19
Value: 2017/10/30 22:41:02
Difference of Timestamp in Seconds:437000
Timestamp:1509383804969 Value:20171030224052
hbase Timestamp 2017/10/30 22:46:44
Value: 2017/10/30 22:40:52
Difference of Timestamp in Seconds:352000
Timestamp:1509383709215 Value:20171030224042
hbase Timestamp 2017/10/30 22:45:09
Value: 2017/10/30 22:40:42
Difference of Timestamp in Seconds:267000
Timestamp:1509383617707 Value:20171030224032
hbase Timestamp 2017/10/30 22:43:37
Value: 2017/10/30 22:40:32
Difference of Timestamp in Seconds:185000
Timestamp:1509383523756 Value:20171030224021
hbase Timestamp 2017/10/30 22:42:03
Value: 2017/10/30 22:40:21
Difference of Timestamp in Seconds:102000
```

When Hbase Timestamp is found we say one request handled.(5 in above output)

(Total start to end time /  number of request) will give me the average throughput.
But I want to write a java code which will find out how many requests have been handled each an every minute(hits per minute) as i want to create a throughput graph.

Even if i can achieve this from any Tool it will be great.
Can anyone please help me?

Comment: Better to use readymade tools for this.

Comment: What i have with me is this output only. How do i use tools like Jmeter ?

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in one of the comments, it would be better to find a tool to use for something like this, however, making a very simple version on your own isn't that complicated but you need to account for some issues like drifting in order to get it spot on.

```
public static void main (String[] args) {
    ThroughputService t = new ThroughputService();

    CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);

    ScheduledExecutorService service = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
    service.scheduleAtFixedRate(t, 0, 1, TimeUnit.MINUTES);

    try {
        latch.await();
    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(NewClass.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

}

static class ThroughputService implements Runnable {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        //code for calculating your throughput
    }

}
```